# nccl - can we sum up all the values of an array on 1 device GPU to obtain the sum?

Tags: arrays, c++11, parallel-processing, cuda

I have a single GPU (e.g. GeForce GTX 980Ti). I have a single float array, for example, cudaMalloc'ed (allocated on that single device GPU) of length 128, with all values being 1.f. I want to use nccl to sum them up to obtain 128, i.e. (1+1+...+1)=128.

However, I read on the NCCL Developer's documentation that the reduction is only across devices, NOT across a single device, if I interpreted it correctly:

cf. http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/nccl-developer-guide/index.html#axzz4rabuBrOP

From there (quoting),

> "AllReduce starts with independent arrays Vk of N values on each of K ranks and ends with identical arrays S of N values, where S[i] = V0 [i]+V1 [i]+…+Vk-1 [i], for each rank k ."

I want to confirm that I cannot do a reduction of an array on the device GPU (summation), on a single GPU.

My full code (and how to compile) is here as reference/context:

https://github.com/ernestyalumni/CompPhys/blob/master/moreCUDA/nccl/Ex01_singleprocess_b.cu

the "meat" of the code is here; the "prep" before (declarations) should be correct:

```
ncclCommCount(*comm.get(),&count);

ncclAllReduce( d_in.get(), d_out.get(), size, 
                ncclFloat, ncclSum, *comm.get(), *stream.get() );

// size is 128 for the 128 elements in both the (pointers to) float arrays 
// d_in and d_out
```

I had "wrapped" my pointers in C++11 smart pointers, but I have tried my code with raw pointers as well with the same result; I can post that version if you'd like.

Please confirm that I cannot use nccl to do parallel reduce on a single device, across a single array on the single device GPU, or show me how I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to confirm that I cannot do a reduction of an array on the device GPU (summation), on a single GPU.

This isn't possible with NCCL.

1. NCCL is designed for multiple GPUs, it's not sensible or logical to attempt to use it for operations involving only a single GPU.
2. The NCCL [Reduce](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/nccl-developer-guide/index.html#reduceop) and [AllReduce](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/nccl-developer-guide/index.html#allreduceop) operations don't perform a reduction on an array to  reduce it to a single number.  They perform reductions on sets of arrays to reduce them to a single array.

My suggestion would be to use a library like [cub](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html) or [thrust](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html) to perform the reduction of an array to a single value on a single GPU.

To explain the difference between NCCL and ordinary reductions (such as those provided by cub or thrust), an ordinary reduction would be like this:

```
arr:
 1
+1
+1
--
 3 (sum) result
```

NCCL Reduce or AllReduce does this:

```
arr1  arr2  arr3      result
 1  +  2  +  3          6
 1  +  3  +  4     =    8
 1  +  4  +  5         10
```

The behavior of NCCL AllReduce is exactly as you already quoted:

> "AllReduce starts with independent arrays Vk of N values on each of K ranks and ends with identical arrays S of N values, where S[i] = V0 [i]+V1 [i]+…+Vk-1 [i], for each rank k ."

Comment: This is good to know and the further explanation both confirms how I read that quote and hopefully will help others too.  Yes, CUB is really good for reduce and scan, especially since it's actively being updated and is both low-level enough to take advantage of nVidia's architecture, and high-level enough to be useful.  Great, thanks!